# php soap entity parameters send

Tags: php, soap

This is soap function.

CreateSales(string UserEmail, string UserPass, string ApiKey, **Entity.Sales Sales**, **List SalesItem**, **Entity.Customer Customer**, **Entity.Payment Payment**, int BranchId, int UserId)

Entity.Sales Sales
List SalesItem
Entity.Customer Customer
Entity.Customer Customer

How can I send values this parameters?

My example code,

```
$result = $client->CreateSales(
    array( 
        "UserEmail" => $this->userEmail, 
        "UserPass" => $this->userPass, 
        "ApiKey" => $this->apikey,
        "Sales" => $client->Sales(
            array(
                "SalesId" => $SalesId,
                "DepartureRegionId" => $DepartureRegionId,
                "DepartureDate" => $DepartureDate,
                "DepartureTime" => $DepartureTime,
                "ArrivalRegionId" => $ArrivalRegionId,
                "TransferTypeId" => $TransferTypeId,
                "PricelistId" => $PricelistId,
                "PricelistIdLineId" => $PricelistIdLineId
            )
        ),
        "SalesItem" => $client->SalesItem(
            array(
                "BranchId" => $this->branchID,
                "SalesDate" => $SalesDate ,
                "ArrivalRegionId" => $ArrivalRegionId,
                "ArrivalDate" => $ArrivalDate,
                "ArrivalTime" => $ArrivalTime,
                "DepartureRegionId" => $DepartureRegionId,
                "DepartureDate" => $DepartureDate,
                "DepartureTime" => $DepartureTime,
                "PaxCount" => $PaxCount,
                "InfantCount" => $InfantCount,
                "Notes" => $Notes,
                "VehicleTypeId" => $VehicleTypeId,
                "VehicleModelId" => $VehicleModelId,
                "VehicleId" => $VehicleId,
                "StatusTypeId" => $StatusTypeId,
                "PricelistId" => $PricelistId,
                "PricelistIdLineId" => $PricelistIdLineId,
                "TransferTypeId" => $TransferTypeId,
                "SalesTypeId" => $SalesTypeId,
                "TransferWayTypeName" => $TransferWayTypeName,
                "TransferDuration" => $TransferDuration,


            )                                                           
        ),
        "Customer" => $client->Customer(
            array(
                "SalesId" => $SalesId,
                "Name" => $Name,
                "Gsm" => $Gsm,
                "AlternativeGsm" => $AlternativeGsm,
                "Email" => $Email,
                "Adress" => $Adress,
                "DepartureInformation" => $DepartureInformation,
                "ArrivalInformation" => $ArrivalInformation,
                "ReturnInformation" => $ReturnInformation,
                "Note" => $Note

            )                                       
        ),
        "Payment" => $client->Payment(
            array("PaymentTypeId"=>2)
        ),
        "BranchId" => $this->branchID,
        "UserId" => $this->userID,
        )
    );
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jens,

My question How can I send entity parameter?

My soapUrl: http://sistem.transferofis.com/service/YurticiTransferService.svc?wsdl
Schema : http://sistem.transferofis.com/service/YurticiTransferService.svc?xsd=xsd2

I use CreateSales function,

CreateSales(string UserEmail, string UserPass, string ApiKey, Entity.Sales Sales, List SalesItem, Entity.Customer Customer, Entity.Payment Payment, int BranchId, int UserId)

No problem string and int parameters. But Entity.Sales Sales,  Entity.Customer Customer, Entity.Payment Payment, How can I send values this parameters.

For example I try in CreateSales function in Sales :

```
                                 "Sales" => $client->Sales(
                                                        array(
                                                            "SalesId" => $SalesId,
                                                            "DepartureRegionId" => $DepartureRegionId,
                                                            "DepartureDate" => $DepartureDate,
                                                            "DepartureTime" => $DepartureTime,
                                                            "ArrivalRegionId" => $ArrivalRegionId,
                                                            "TransferTypeId" => $TransferTypeId,
                                                            "PricelistId" => $PricelistId,
                                                            "PricelistIdLineId" => $PricelistIdLineId
                                                        )
                                                    ),
```